# Seg fault...on hello world

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

This code is really simple and I am getting a seg fault on my x86_64 linux system. It is bothering me a lot. Just getting started with asm so please have patience!

Assembled with NASM
`nasm -f elf64 test.asm`

linked with
`ld -o test test.o`

```
SECTION .text
    GLOBAL _start

    _start:
        ; print name
        mov eax,4     ; sys_write
        mov ebx,1     ; stdout
        mov ecx,name  ; start address of name
        mov edx,1     ; length
        int 80H       ; syscall

        ; exit program
        mov eax,1     ; sys_exit
        mov ebx,0     ; success
        int 80H       ; sys_call  

SECTION .data
    name DB 'R'
```

My machine: Gentoo x86_64 nomultilib! I compiled my own kernel without IA32 emulation. I should have stated that my system is a 64 bit only system. Would this attribute to the errors I am receiving?

```
$ uname -a
Linux rcepeda 4.4.1-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 3 13:12:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Solution

use 64 bit registers and 64bit linux dispatcher

use syscall (not int 80H).

**Thank you Nate and Michael**

[32 Bit Linux SYSCALL TABLE](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html)

[64 Bit Linux SYSCALL TABLE](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64)

```
SECTION .text
    GLOBAL _start

    _start:
        ; print name
        mov rax,1     ; sys_write
        mov rdi,1     ; stdout
        mov rsi,name  ; start address of name
        mov rdx,7 ; length
        syscall

        ; exit program
        mov rax,60    ; sys_exit
        mov rdi,0     ; success
        syscall

SECTION .data
    name DB "Rafael",10
```

.

```
rafael@rcepeda ~/asm $ ./a.out 
Rafael
```

Comment: works for me. what is your `uname -a`?

Comment: Is this code what you are actually testing with? Your title suggests this is Hello World but I don't see how this prints Hello World. If you are not posting your real code, and if it isn't too long can you edit your question with the code you are actually using?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: It prints `R` instead of `Hello world`, that's all.  But otherwise it's real code.

Comment: @NateEldredge I know it is a complete example, but it is possible the user is not giving us his exact code. Since his title suggests a different output may suggest that the code seg faulting may not be the code being showed. I am therefore requesting clarification. Unless this code is operating outside the lower 4gb address space, it should work even though it is a 64-bit app using a 32-bit `int 0x80` mechanism.

Comment: I also am with @YOU . I'm very curious what `uname -a` returns. It would be helpful to show that in your question

Comment: This is the exact code. It is essentially a hello world example as @NateEldredge mentioned. Sorry if I did not clarify that.

Comment: 1) See the last lines of `dmesg`: the kernel will write why the process was terminated 2) Check the return code of `sys/write`, found in `%rax` or with a debugger/`strace`.

Comment: I believe now your question may explain your problem. I've never disabled IA32 emulation on the Linux Kernel, but I imagine that doing so may remove the `int 0x80` support that exists to support 32-bit system calls (via int 0x80). If that in fact is the case (I'm not sure) you probably would be forced into using the `syscall` interface as Nate mentioned. Consider using 64-bit `syscall`. A useful table for `syscall` is [here](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) or reference Nate's answer/link.

Comment: Likely had you built your kernel with IA32 emulation support your program probably would have worked. Most Linux distros enable IA32 emulation with their 64-bit kernel, so that there can be backward compatibility with older 32-bit user code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch awesome thank you for your help. I will try that when I get home from work! Thank you for your help

Comment: One more question, in 64bit asm, am I not allow to use any 32bit register?

Comment: You are able to use 32-bit registers in 64-bit code. 32-bit operands generate a 32-bit result,zero-extended to a 64-bit result in the destination general-purpose register. So if you have a 32-bit general register as an operand and put a value in it, the processor zero extends the result across the entire 64-bit register. You can use 16 and 8 bit register operands too, but when writing to them they are not zero extended to to the entire 64-bit register. Short answer is yes, you can use 8/16/32/64 bit registers in 64-bit code. In your case the issue is likely an unsupported `int 0x80` interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running in 64-bit mode but this is 32-bit code.  If you want 64-bit code, you'll have to rewrite it.

You should be using the 64-bit registers `rax, rbx`, etc.  And in 64-bit Linux, system calls are no longer made with `int 80h` but with the new `syscall` instruction.  See http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/linuxsyscalls/ for an example (note this uses AT&T assembler syntax instead of Intel).

Alternatively, you can keep the code the same, and assemble and link it in 32-bit mode, using `nasm -f elf32` and `ld -m elf_i386`.  But then you're learning (relatively) obsolete technology.  (Edit: Actually, it appears 32-bit compatibility is not enabled on your particular system, so this won't work at all for you.)

Comment: This 32-bit code should work in a 64-bit Linux environment since the example shown in all likelihood is not running outside the bottom 4gb of the address space. `int 0x80` is still available in 64-bit code, but isn't the preferred mechanism. One situation that would force the usage of `syscall` would be accessing memory on the stack. Since the stack values in 64-bit are above 4gb they get truncated and are useless with a 32-bit `int 0x80` call.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing but in theory a 32bit register is the same as a 64bit one just half the size as @MichaelPetch states. My system is strictly 64bit though, I do not have multilib support on my system and no IA32 emulation on my kernel. Seems something to do with my machine but I am not sure what it is....

Comment: Thank you for the link Nate, it seems just about what I am doing on my 64bit machine. I will try this out when I get home. My system is strictly 64bit, I did not know however that I cannot use my 32bit registers then????

Comment: @Rafael: In general, you can use the 32-bit registers in 64-bit mode.  But for example, in 64-bit mode, the second argument of `write(2)` is meant to be a pointer, which should be 64 bits.  When you move the address of `name` into `ecx`, you end up with the low half of `rcx`  containing the low 32 bits of the address, and the high half containing 0.  The kernel is going to be looking for a 64-bit pointer in `rcx`.  If the address isn't in the low 2 GB of the address space, then the result will be wrong.  So you can *use* the 32-bit registers, but it may not be the right thing to do.