# Linux Assembly x86_64 create a file using command line parameters

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to teach myself assembly. I've found a good [website](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/quickstart.html#cmdarg_file); however, everything is written for x86 and I use a 64-bit machine.

I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it. If I run the program with strace, then here is the results:

```
execve("./file", ["./file", "hello"], [/* 94 vars */]) = 0
creat(NULL, 0)                          = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(0, NULL, 0 <unfinished ...>
+++ exited with 234 +++
```

So, I know that when I call `creat`, that the file name "hello" is not being passed and as a result I don't have a file descriptor.

Here is the code in question:

```
section .text
  global _start

_start:
  pop rbx ; argc
  pop rbx ; prog name
  pop rbx ; the file name

  mov eax,85 ; syscall number for creat()
  mov ecx,00644Q ; rw,r,r
  int 80h ; call the kernel
```

I know that I can use the `syscall` command; however, I want to use interrupt.

Any ideas or suggestions would be helpful. Also, I'm using nasm an assembler.

Comment: If you are writing 64-bit code, you will save yourself a lot of time and energy if you switch to _SYSCALL_. Although `int 0x80` can be made to work in 64-bit code in some cases, anything that might contain an address on the stack will not work as a pointer with `int 0x80`. The last `pop rbx` will put an address in _RBX_ which points to the string. That address usually points to another place on the stack. A pointer to data on the stack generally can't be passed to `int 0x80` using the lower 32-bits of the address (_EBX_ in this case)  and will usually end with a seg fault b/c of a Bad Address.

Comment: Three `pop`s into the same register is a weird way to get to `argv[1]`.  I guess it's actually fewer code bytes than `mov rbx,  [rsp+16]`, and thanks to the red zone in the x86-64 Linux ABI, `argc` and `argv[0]` aren't in danger of being clobbered asynchronously even though they're below `rsp`.  (Although AFAIK nothing can use the stack asynchronously other than signal handlers, and you obviously don't install any.)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Usually the system call will just fail, leaving `-EFAULT` in `eax`, but not crash your program.  This is confusing for people that don't at least use `strace` as a substitute for checking return values (which is inconvenient enough in C).

Comment: Write the programs in C. Compile to assembler (`-c -S`) without optimizations. Do it again with optimizations (e.g., `-O2`). Pencil, paper, and a copy of the x86-64 ELF ABI, until it all clicks:) It seems like flippant advice, but I think it's good.

Comment: @PeterCordes How could there be a race condition? The code is sequential.

Comment: @SailorCire: There can't be in this case, because you don't have a signal handler, but leaving data below `rsp` is dangerous in general.  A unix process can receive a signal from another process at any time.  See `kill(2)`.  If a process has installed a signal handler, and hasn't set it up to use an alt stack (`sigaltstack(2)`), the kernel will execute the signal hander with its `rsp` pointing just below the red-zone in the current stack.  IDK what other mechanisms could asynchronously clobber space below the stack, but possibly some debuggers might?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You attempted to use the 32 bit mechanism. If you have a 32 bit tutorial, you can of course create 32 bit programs and those will work as-is in compatibility mode.
If you want to write 64 bit code however, you will need to use the 64 bit conventions and interfaces. Here, that means the `syscall` instruction with the appropriate registers:

```
  global _start

_start:
  mov eax,85       ; syscall number for creat()
  mov rdi,[rsp+16] ; argv[1], the file name
  mov esi,00644Q   ; rw,r,r
  syscall          ; call the kernel 
  xor edi, edi     ; exit code 0
  mov eax, 60      ; syscall number for exit()
  syscall
```

See also the x86-64 sysv abi on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) or the [abi pdf](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Not sure it is worth mentioning that one reason `int 0x80` won't work here is that `[rsp+16]` usually contains an address that points into the stack, and of course 64-bit stack based addresses (the way Linux uses them) can't be represented in a 32-bit register so won't work with the `int 0x80` convention. I totally agree they should be using `syscall` and I was curious as to why the OP didn't want to go that route.

Comment: Also, the `int 0x80` is just for the 32 bit compatibility mode and could theoretically be disabled in a pure 64 bit system. Of course nobody does that in practice.

Comment: Absolutely! People shouldn't be using `int 0x80`, and quite correct - with IA32 emulation turned off it won't work period. I seem to recall answering a question about that in the past month or so.

Comment: Oh it wasn't an answer, it was in the comments of this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546021/seg-fault-on-hello-world  . Someone couldn't get `int 0x80` to work, and discovered that had built their kernel without IA32 emulation.